# Collect data from html text field and popup radio button and insert in db

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I have an html page with a text field and two types of submit buttons.For example post and comment.When post is selected a particular php should be selected which is working good.But when comment is selected a pop comes with radio buttons yes/no then if submitted the radio button data and the text field data should be displayed and inserted in db which is not happening

HTML code :

```
<form id="contactform" method="post" action="localhost/1.php">
  Input:<br>
  <input type="text" name="Input"><br>
  <button type="submit"> Post</button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" >Comment</button>
  <button type="submit" formaction="home.php">Cancel</button>
</form>
```

Here when comment is selected a popup comes with radio buttons:

```
<div class = "modal fade" id = "myModal" tabindex = "-1" role = "dialog" 
   aria-labelledby = "myModalLabel" aria-hidden = "true">
      <div class = "modal-dialog">
        <div class = "modal-content">
           <div class = "modal-header">
              <button type = "button" class = "close" data-dismiss = "modal" aria-hidden = "true">&times;</button>
                 <h4 class = "modal-title" id = "myModalLabel">
                 Sure to comment!
                 </h4>
           </div>
        <div class = "modal-body">
          <tr>
            <td style="padding-bottom: 0px;">
               <input type="radio" name="action" value="Yes"> Yes
               <input type="radio" name="action" value="No"> No<br>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </div>
        <div class = "modal-footer">
            <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-default" data-dismiss = "modal">
               Cancel
            </button>
            <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-primary">
               submit
            </button>
         </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

When a choice of yes or no is selected and submit is selected i want a separate php to run where the data(radio button data and text field) should be collected and inserted in db

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's certainly possible to do this but you're missing all of your JavaScript logic. If you want to do it without JavaScript .. that's going to be hard.

Comment: `action="localhost/1.php"` this is failing you. It requires an http call. Either that, or remove `localhost/`

Comment: you tagged as php/jquery/mysql with no code to support the question. This tells me you either tagged wrong, or want us to write this for you.

Comment: @Fred i just gave an example localhost/1.php....the action for 1.php is working,And i want to know in what all ways this can be done so tagged jquery

Answer (score 0):

So you are posting data to 1.php? And you have 1 input field and radio buttons?

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['Input']) && isset($_POST['action'])){

  //The data was posted to 1.php
  $input = $_POST['Input'];
  $action = $_POST['action'];

  //Now check the radio button

  if ($action == "Yes") {

    //They selected the yes option, do something.
    //Using mysqli or PDO insert into database.

  } else {

    //They didn't select the yes option, so it has to be no - Now do something.
    //Using mysqli or PDO insert into database.

  }

}
?>
```

Do not forget to use proper security techniques when dealing with user input.